# select query with time_stamp difference in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i want a query to find the data from less than some value and greater than some value with time stamp gap is 5 min.

for example 20.4 is <= 26.0 and 25.5 also <= 26.0 but the time_stamp value diffrence is just 3 min  so i want select the 20.4,40.1,22.3,32.2

```
20.4    October, 26 2013 13:12:22+0000
25.5    October, 26 2013 13:15:22+0000
40.1    October, 26 2013 13:35:22+0000
22.3    October, 26 2013 13:43:22+0000
19.78   October, 26 2013 13:45:22+0000
32.2    October, 26 2013 13:51:22+0000
```

but i want result set like,

```
20.4    October, 26 2013 13:12:22+0000
40.1    October, 26 2013 13:35:22+0000
22.3    October, 26 2013 13:43:22+0000
32.2    October, 26 2013 13:51:22+0000
```

please find the sql fiddle [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e67b3/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT type,time_stamp
FROM (
   select type,time_stamp,
          if(time_stamp > @prev_tm + interval 5 minute, 
             (@prev_tm:=time_stamp), @prev_tm ) prev_tm
   from table1,
   (
      SELECT (@prev_tm:= min(time_stamp) - interval 999 minute)
      FROM table1
   ) init_vars
   where time_stamp >= '2013-10-26 13:12:22'
   and (type <= 26 or type >= 30)
   order by time_stamp
) sub_query
WHERE time_stamp = prev_tm
```

demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e67b3/24